# Convert Links to another link - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example- i was shared some (near 100+) page links of my frnd's site `www.lol.com` on my website. but after some days my friend changed his website link to `www.lolz.com` .

So how to change `www.lol.com` to `www.lolz.com` with the help of javascript on my site without changing manually those links which were shared by me before .

Comment: Why not just change the original links? I don't think you'll regret this decision in the long run. Having the page source contain incorrect links that are modified by javascript seems like a hassle and likely to cause issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var allAnchors = document.getElementsBytagName('a');
for (var a = 0; a < allAnchors.length; a++){
  if (allAnchors[a].href.indexOf('lol.com') != -1){
    allAnchors[a].href = allAnchors[a].href.replace('lol.com','lolz.com');
  }
}
```

Rudimentary, but should work. Also, I would advise your friend to create a domain forward of lol.com to point to lolz.com. It's their issue as the site author to handle this, not you.

And, the jQuery approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*="lol.com"]').attr('href',function(orig){
      return orig.replace('lol.com','lolz.com');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: **I would advise your friend to create a domain forward of lol.com to point to lolz.com. It's their issue as the site author to handle this, not you.** - hehehehe..... he is crazy! nd im super crazy!!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? It's not executing, it is executing by not replacing, you're using the jQuery version and may not have wrapped it in `$(document).ready(...)`, ...?

Comment: jquery ver- 1.7.1
i insert dat code like it- `<script> $('a[href*="lol.com"]').attr('href',function(orig){
  return orig.replace('lol.com','lolz.com');
}); </script>` is it wrt ?

Comment: @BPP: see my updated answer and copy that directly in to your page below jQuery's `<script src="..."></script>` inclusion. Also, please try to use english (_please_, _that_, _right_, _the_) as not everyone on the "interwebz" is an elitist.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( function() {
$("a[href=http://www.lol.com]").attr("src", "http://www.lolz.com");
});
```

Comment: `<a>` doesn't have a `src` attribute; but a `href` exists. ;-)

Comment: @BPP i was in hurry and Brad Sorry :D